# Get member always returning None in modmail feature [discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a Modmail feature in a server, what the feature does:

1- Once the user dms the bot, a channel in the modmail category is created, the channel name is the same as the user ID that dm'd the bot.

2- Any message sent by the user to the bot afterwards is sent to the modmail channel.

3- Any message sent in the modmail channe is dm'd to the user.

The way the bot knows who to send the message to is by the channel name, because the channel name equals the ID of the user that opened the ticket, however, when the bot tries to get the member with the ID in the channel name, it always returns None.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = bot.get_guild(704414884187602994) ## Get the modmail guild
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=754287971347464223) ## Get the modmail category
    overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
} ## Permissions for ticket channel
    
    if isinstance(message.channel, DMChannel): ## Check if a user dms the bot
        if message.author != bot.user: ## Doesn't make the bot respond to itself
            channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=f"{message.author.id}") ## Ticket channel
            if channel is None: ## Check if there is no open tickets for this user
                await message.channel.send("Welcome to Modmail!") ## Sends message when user dms the bot
                await category.create_text_channel(name=f"{message.author.id}", overwrites=overwrites) ## Create ticket channel if none found
            elif channel is not None: ## If ticket found
                await channel.send(f"Message recieved from {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}, content: {message.content}") ## Send message to ticket channel
    if message.channel.category == category: ## If a message is sent to the ticket channel
        TheID = message.channel.name ## The ticket channel name which is the same name as the reporter ID
        reporter = guild.get_member(TheID) ## Get the reporter to send messages to
        print(TheID) ## Print the ID of the reporter
        if reporter is None: ## If no user has the ID given in the channel name
            print("Member not found.")
        else:   
            await reporter.send(f"Message recieved from bot, content = {message.content}") ## Send message to reporter
```

Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is at this line `TheID = message.channel.name`

[`TextChannel.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.name) returns a string that is the name of the channel, and get_member() required ID which should be Integer, so you should do `reporter = guild.get_member(int(TheID))`

Comment: For future searchers, this change was due to the Discord API update where ids changed to ints. 
You'll also need to register for the members intent for accurate guild members listing. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64221473/2983132

Answer (score 0):

````
        TheID = message.channel.name 
        reporter = guild.get_member(int(TheID)) 
        print(TheID) 
        if reporter is None: 
            print("Member not found.")
        else:   
            await reporter.send(f"Message recieved from bot, content = {message.content}")```
````